# 日本語に違和感: 日時を mm/dd hh:mm で表記する場合に、日付と時刻の間にある「の」は不要

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問一覧にて:  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions

[image: 質問一覧での例]

8月30日 10:08 などが自然だと思います。

Comment: 日時を直すときにこれも直します。